# How to use an IF statement for multiple cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this statement as the IF statement

```
=IF(AND(C5,D5,E5,F5,G5,H5,I5= "x"),"1","0")
```

However it only marks a 1 if the last one has an x in it, I want it to check if whether those cells all have x then it should have a 1, otherwise it would be a 0.

Comment: Could you possibly show an example? @K.Dᴀᴠɪs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with an array formula with a range as an argument:

```
=IF(AND(C5:I5="x"),"1","0")
```

(You'll need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm it as an array formula.)

Comment: all you really need is `=--AND(C5:I5="x")` with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: @ScottCraner True, as long as OP wants numerical output instead of text output.

Answer (score 0):

The `AND` function treats all statements individually:  `AND(A1, A2="x")` would mean *"The value in A1 is TRUE and the value in A2 is 'x'"* - to check if they are both "x", you need to explicitly state this in each statement: `AND(A1="x", A2="x")`

Bonus points - changing `TRUE` or `FALSE` to `1` or `0` is easy - just add a double negation (`--`) before the boolean:  (And wrap in `TEXT` to change it to a string instead of a number)

`=TEXT(--AND(C5="x", D5="x", E5="x", F5="x", G5="x", H5="x", I5="x"), "0")`

Answer (score 0):

Without array formula:

```
=--(COUNTIF(C5:I5,"x")=6)&IF(,,)
```